# How to convert string to variable name which will be passed into plot function

Tags: matlab

How I can convert a string to a variable which will be passed into plot function?

```
Time = [0,1,2,3];
A = sin(Time);
B = cos(Time);
c = 2*sin(Time);

lookup = {"A", "Freq(Hz)"; "B", "Pressure(bar)", "c", "time(ms),....};

for i=1:length(lookup)
    plot(Time, lookup(i,1))
    ylabel(lookup(i,2))
end
```

I want to plot `Time` vs `A` and `Time` vs `B` and `Time` vs `C` likewise I have 50 different variables to plot.

So I planned to create the lookup with string and planned to pass as variable to plot function using `eval` function call.

But in few places I read that using `eval` is not good option so kindly suggest the alternate method.

Comment: Use a struct or a cell to store your data in. Since they're all in the same plot, I presume they depict the same physical quantity (plotting pressure, frequency and time in one plot, along with 47 other physical quantities is probably meaningless anyway). Store in a cell or struct, and simply loop over that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will solve your immediate problem:

Replace

```
lookup = {"A", "Freq(Hz)"; "B", "Pressure(bar)", "c", "time(ms)", ...};
```

with

```
lookup = {A, "Freq(Hz)"; B, "Pressure(bar)", c, "time(ms)", ...};
```

Cell arrays are *heterogeneous* containers, each element can be an array of any time, independently from all other types.

With this change, the rest of your code should work as intended. You might want to add a `figure` command or a `print` command inside your loop, as each plot will overwrite the previous one. `figure` creates a new figure window to plot in, you'll have 50 windows (not so nice). `print` can save the plot to a file, which might be a better approach here. Don't try to combine the 50 data lines into a single plot, it'll be a mess!

---

On a larger scale, you might want to rethink your strategy with defining 50 different variables. Cell arrays and struct arrays are really good ways to go about this. For example, you can think of

```
data.A = sin(Time);
data.B = cos(Time);
data.c = 2*sin(Time);
```

or

```
data(1).values = sin(Time);
data(1).name = "A";
data(1).units = "Freq(Hz)";
data(2).values = cos(Time);
data(2).name = "B";
data(2).units = "Pressure(bar)";
data(3).values = 2*sin(Time);
data(3).name = "c";
data(3).units = "time(ms)";
```

Note that, in the first case, you can also index with `data.("A")`, which brings you pretty close to your original idea, except that you don't have 50 variables in your workspace, but one single data structure that is easier to deal with.

---

[Here is a very detailed list of reasons why `eval` can be bad to use](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/304528-tutorial-why-variables-should-not-be-named-dynamically-eval). That link also shows some alternatives, similar to what I summarized above.